Can any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be covered with countably many open Euclidean balls of fixed radius whose centers belong to the set
Here it is argued that any set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be covered by countably many balls. My question is can the centers of these balls be taken within the set?
I can prove this easily by assuming the Axiom of Choice (AC). I wonder if there exists a proof without using it?
For completeness I will add the proof with AC.
Let $r > 0$ be arbitrary, and our set of interest be called $S$. Observe that we can cover the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ with open balls $B(p, r/2)$ where $p$ is a point with rational entries, i.e., $p \in \mathbb{Q}^n$. So $\mathbb{R}^n = \bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{Q}^n}B(p, r/2)$.
Exclude any $p$ such that $B(p, r/2) \cap S = \varnothing$, and let $P = \{p \in \mathbb{Q}^n: B(p, r/2) \cap S \neq \varnothing\}$. These are clearly countably many points and in addition $S \subset \bigcup_{p \in P} B(p,r/2)$. Using the axiom of choice pick a point form each of the sets $B(p,r/2) \cap S$ for $p \in P$, and call this selection $f(p) \in S$. Consider now $\bigcup_{p \in P} B(f(p), r)$. This is a countable collection which covers $S$. This is so since $B(p,r/2) \subset B(f(p), r)$ since for any $x \in B(p,r/2)$ we have by the triangle inequality $\|x-f(p)\| \leq \|x- p\| + \|p- f(p)\| < r$.

I don't think it is likely. It is known that countable choice for reals is equivalent to that there is a subspace of the reals that is Lindelöf but not compact. (See Theorem 7.2 of Herrlich's Axiom of Choice.)
